# Why do I get an unexpected keyword argument?

Tags: django, django-models, typeerror, keyword-argument

I have created a model in my Djano project and the name of the model is Questions in which I have created a primary key called questionid. I am able to get all listings as summaries on one page however when I try to get a detailed listing of one query (say question number 4 out of the several in the table) by going to the http://127.0.0.1:8000/qanda/4 (here 4 is the question number), I get an error that says

TypeError at /qanda/4
question() got an unexpected keyword argument 'question_questionid'

Please see the code below

In my model's views file

```
def question(request):
questionsm = Questions.objects.order_by('-published_date').filter(is_published=True)
context = {
     'questionid': questionsm
 }
return render(request,'qanda/question.html', context)
```

In my model url file

```
path('<int:question_questionid>', views.question, name='question'),
```

I will appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Any url parameter must be taken care of by the url handler, So your `views.question` is expected to handle a parameter `question_questionid` and btw, Just name it pk

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the var to the view.

```
def question(request, **id_what_you_want**):
    # and if you want an individual view, you should get by id
    Questions.objects.get(pk=id_what_you_want)
```